# Number is too large Exception in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to print this integer number

```
 int a=07;
System.out.println("Value of a is "+a);
```

it runs and shows `value of a is 7` but when i change the value of a

```
 int a=08;
System.out.println("Value of a is "+a);
```

then it shows `integer number too large`

I dont know why... Can any body tell me ?

Comment: @BalusC thankx fr respnse  please explain in few lines here

Comment: Bad exception message from JVM IMHO as int b=a; won't even compile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's beause the JVM interprets this number as `octal`, and there's no symbol `8` in octal.

Any number starting by `0` is an octal number.

Comment: i understand it but if 0 to 7 are octal numbers then 07*07 why its answer is 49 ?

Comment: Because the result is expressed in decimal. `07` in octal is exactly the same as `7 ` in decimal.  `07 x 07 = 061` and `061=47`

Comment: you are saying that 061=47 but answer is 49 not 47?

Comment: Excuseme, that was a typo, I should have said: `061=49`

Comment: In java if i am multiplying two octal numbers then how i will get its result in octal?

Comment: I any language, numbers are numbers. If you want to represent ANY number in other system, you must tell so to the outputing libraries. In the particular case of java, you can use: `Integer.toOctalString( 49 )`

Comment: Glad to have helped you

Answer (score 0):

`08` is octal 8 which is not valid since octal numbers are only from 0 to 7.

You should try:

```
int a=8;
System.out.println("Value of a is "+a);
```